# how to see if a string array contains the same strings as another string array java

Tags: arrays

Im trying to check to see if the array arr2 is contained within the arr1 in the same order without java utils. The arr2 could be contained anywhere with in arr1.

```
    contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2"}) → true
    contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", "3"}) → true
    contains({"1", "2", "3"}, {"2", "1"}) → false
```

this is what i've tried so far

```
    public boolean contains(String[] arr1, String[] arr2)
    {
    if(arr2.length>arr1.length)
    return false;

    for(int i =0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
    if(arr1[i] == arr2[0])
     return true;
    if(arr1 [i+1]!= arr2[0+i])
      return false;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction and what have you tried?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940194/find-an-array-inside-another-larger-array ?