# Finding if an array contains all elements in another array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to loop through 2 arrays, the outer array is longer then the other. It will loop through the first and if the 2nd array does not contain that int it will return a false. But I cannot figure out how to go about this. This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
  for (int i = 0; i < outer.length; i++) {
    if (!inner.contains(outer[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I am getting this error when run:

```
Cannot invoke contains(int) on the array type int[]
```

I am wondering if it can be done without using a nested loop (like above). I know I'm doing something wrong and if anyone could help on the matter it would be great. Also I wasn't sure what class to look for in the java doc for the `int[]`.

Comment: You're trying to identify whether or not the arrays have any elements in common, correct?

Comment: Well yes, I am trying to determin if the first array has all the elements of the 2nd.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940194/find-an-array-inside-another-larger-array

Comment: The only thing you can really expect is **hiding** the nested loop (or both loops). Internally, it will always need to loop through the arrays...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could check that the larger of the arrays `outer` contains every element in the smaller one, i.e. `inner`:

```
public static boolean linearIn(Integer[] outer, Integer[] inner) {

   return Arrays.asList(outer).containsAll(Arrays.asList(inner));
}
```

Note: `Integer` types are required for this approach to work. If primitives are used, then  `Arrays.asList` will return a `List` containing a single element of type `int[]`. In that case, invoking `containsAll` will not check the actual content of the arrays but rather compare the primitive `int` array `Object` references.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `contains` then you need an ArrayList. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Otherwise, you need two loops.

There is a workaround like this:

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
    List<Integer> innerAsList = arrayToList(inner);
    for (int i = 0; i < outer.length; i++) {
      if (!innerAsList.contains(outer[i])) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}  

private List<Integer> arrayToList(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> result= new ArrayList<Integer>(arr.length);
    for (int i : arr) {
        result.add(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But don't think that looping is not happening, just because you don't see it. If you check the implementation of the ArrayList you would see that there is a for loop:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.indexOf(java.lang.Object)
So you are not gaining any performance. You know your model best, and you might be able to write more optimized code.

Comment: How about `Arrays.asList(inner).containsAll(Arrays.asList(outer))`

Comment: `Arrays.asList(inner)` returns a list with one `int[]` item. It is probably not doing what the OP expects.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options using `java.util.Arrays` if you don't want to implement it yourself:

- [`Arrays.toList(array).contains(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) which does exactly you are doing right now. It is the best thing to do if your array is not guaranteed to be sorted.
- [`Arrays.binarySearch(x,array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) provided if your array is sorted. It returns the index of the value you are search for, or a negative value. It will be much, much faster than regular looping.

Answer (score 1):

The question above is a practice in my class. There is my friend' solution:

```
public boolean contains(int[] arrA, int[] arrB) {
    if (arrB.length > arrA.length) return false;
    if (arrB.length == 0 && arrA.length == 0) return false;
    for (int count = 0, i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
        if (arrA[i] == arrB[count]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        if (count == arrB.length) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int[] is a primitive array. Meaning it does not have any special methods attached to it. You would have to manually write your own contains method that you can pass the array and the value to.

Alternatively you could use an array wrapper class such as ArrayList which does have a .contains method.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inner = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean containsOne = inner.contains(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

contain method is reserved for ArrayList
Try this:

```
public boolean linearIn(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
        for (int i = 0; i < outer.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {
                if (outer[i] == inner[j])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be if (outer[i] != inner[j]) or am I missing something?