# Checking if a row of a 2-dimensional array exists anywhere within another array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following sorted array:

`int[] numbers = {0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2}`.

How can I check if any sub-array of length 3 of `numbers` exists in the following 2-dimensional array:

`int[][] sets = { {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2} }`

In this simple example, the last 3 elements of `numbers` are clearly contained as an array in `sets`, but in my actual program, `sets` will have far more 3 digit permutations of more numbers, but they will all remain length 3, and `numbers` will always be sorted.

Comment: What's the max number allowed in the three-item sets?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure yet. It won't be high at all, probably < 10. Just take it that only numbers 0-3 inclusive are allowed for now

Comment: `Arrays.asList(outer).containsAll(Arrays.asList(inner))` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524709/finding-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-in-another-array

Comment: @tak3shi I tried using this solution, but I came across a problem when duplicate numbers appear in the inner array. In other words, take my example above. `sets[0][0] = {0, 0, 0}`. For `Arrays.asList(numbers).containsAll(Arrays.asList(inner))` to be evaluated to true, `numbers` only needs to contain one 0, whereas my algorithm would need it to contain three different 0s.

Answer (score 0):

If only the numbers less than ten are allowed, you have up to 1000 possible sequences of three numbers. Encode them as 100*a<sub>i</sub>+10*a<sub>i+1</sub>+a<sub>i+2</sub>, and store the index of the first such sequence in a 1001-element array.

In your case `numbers` would be translated into

0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2

```
  1 - 0
 12 - 1
122 - 2
222 - 3
```

The first column is the index into 1001-element array; the second column is the value that gets placed at that index. The remaining positions of the 1001-element array are set to -1.

To see if `numbers` contain a three-element sequence construct 100*s<sub>0</sub>+10*s<sub>1</sub>+s<sub>2</sub> number from them, and look it up in the 1001-element array. If you get -1, the sequence is not there; otherwise, you would get the starting index of the desired subsequence.