# Java matching patterns in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, pattern-matching, arr

I have two char arrays (e.g. `arr[]1 {'w','o','r','d'}` and `arr[]2 {'o','r'})` and need to check for pattern occurrence of `arr[]2` in `arr[]1` (All values of `arr2` must be present in `arr1` in the same sequential order).

I already solved this by converting to strings and using regex.
However, I was wondering if this could be solved without building strings consisting of the chars in each array.

Is it possible to check if an entire array is part of another one in JAVA (while keeping continuity/index sequence in account) or do I have to iterate through each value `[n], [n+1],... [arr2.length]` of `arr2` and see if it is present in `arr1[indexofFoundChar],[index+1]...` and so on.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding if an array contains all elements in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524709/finding-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-in-another-array)

Comment: Still using `String`, but without regex: `String.valueOf(arr1).contains(String.valueOf(arr2))`.

Comment: why not just use String and its `contains` methods, no need for regex... if you really need to do it yourself hava a look at the implementation of `contains`, or more precisely, `indexOf()`

Comment: what about `arr[1]1 {'w', 'o', 'x', 'r'}` should it return `true` for above `arr[]2` ?

Comment: {'w', 'o', 'x', 'r'} should return false, {'w', 'o', 'r', 'x'} for example should return true.

Comment: How large are your arrays?

Comment: rather small, they consist of about 5-15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

For so small arrays direct comparison (brute-force approach) should be enough.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lenA - lenB; i++)  {
   int j = 0;
   while (j < lenB) && (B[j] = A[i+j])
      j++; 
   if (j==lenB)
       return true;
}
return false;
```

It works fast but becomes quadratic when repeating/partially matched patterns occur (like "abcabcd" when you look for "abcd")

For larger arrays choose any simple [string searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) like Boyer-Moore, Knutt-Morris-Pratt, Rabin-Karp ones - but apply them to array items, not strings.