# Easily Change the .contains() method in the Collections interface in Java for Asserting Equality

Tags: java, collections, interface, equals, contains

I'm wondering if there is a way to easily modify the ".contains()" method in the List interface in Java without creating a custom class. For example:

When dealing with a collection of arrays in java, the .contains() method will always return false because the .contains() method always checks for equality with a generic .equals() call from the Object class that only returns true if the compared objects have the same reference in memory. However, with arrays, it is much more useful to do an Arrays.equals() check on the two arrays.

Code:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myIntArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
        List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(myIntArray);
        System.out.println(myList.contains(new int[] {1, 2, 3}));
    } // Output in the console: false
    // Preferred output: true
}
```

I understand that it is possible to do this rather easily by using a for loop and iterating over the whole list using the Arrays.equals() method, but the goal for me is to learn how to easily sculpt the .contains() method into what I need for future use. Thanks a lot!

Comment: looking for `containsAll`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding if an array contains all elements in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524709/finding-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-in-another-array)

Comment: @Naman Not quite. The containsAll method would be useful if I were comparing a List of Integers to another, but in this case I'm comparing a List of int[] and an int[]. It would be possible to convert each int[] to a List equivalent, but it would be nice if I didn't have to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `contains()` can't do anything other than use `Object.equals`, because that's required by the specification.

That's not to say that it's not reasonable to want a notion of contains for an array; merely that you can't overload the existing concept.

You can straightforwardly create a static method:

```
static <T> boolean containsArray(List<? extends T[]> list, T[] query) {
  return list.stream().anyMatch(e -> Arrays.equals(e, query));
}
```

And then invoke this where you would otherwise invoke `list.contains(query)`.

This has the advantage that it works for *any* list (with reference-typed array elements): you don't have to create it specially, merely update these specialized comparisons.

(The above would work for any reference-typed array. You'd need to specialize it for primitive-typed arrays).

It also has the advantage that you don't have to deal with the thorny consequences highlighted by [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61427886/3788176) (e.g. how `indexOf`, `remove` etc work).

---

There's another alternative: use a list element type which supports equals "correctly". For example, you can wrap arrays using `Arrays.asList` to store them in the list, so you have a `List<List<T>>` instead of `List<T[]>`.

This would be quite an invasive change: it would require changing the type of the list throughout your code; you've not provided any indication of how pervasively-used your list of arrays is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Marking it as final response.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is a way to easily modify the `contains` method in the `List` interface in Java without creating a custom class.

There isn't a way.  The `contains` method of the standard implementations of `List` behave as specified by the `List` API; i.e. they use the `equals` method.

The flip-side that it would not be hard to extend the `ArrayList` class and override `contains` to do what you want.  But if you are doing it properly, you need to consider whether you want:

- `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to be consistent with `contains`
- the semantics of `equals(Object)` to be consistent with it
- the semantics of a list returned by `sublist(int, int)` to be consistent with the semantics of the main list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!