# Answer consists out of certain characters

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] colors = {"R", "G", "B", "P", "O", "Y"};
String guess = "";
String valid = false;


//Get Input
guess = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();

// Change String Array to Regular String
String Colors = "";
for(int i=0; i<colors.length; i++) {
    Colors += colors[i];
}

// See if Guess Consists out of Correct Letters
if(guess.matches(Colors)) {
    valid = true;
}
```

Basically what I want to achieve with this code is to check if the input given meets the requirements.

In this case does `guess` only consists of the letters given in `colors`, for example:

if `guess = RGB` then `valid = true`

if `guess = RGBA` then `valid = false`

I know I can also put it in manually like this:

```
if(guess.matches("[RGBPOY]+")) {
    valid = true;
}
```

But I want to keep it procedural.

Is there a way to get this working? Or am I better off using a different method like say a for loop?

I only recently started with JAVA and am not yet familiar with all the different approaches it has to offer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java) or [Finding if an array contains all elements in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524709/finding-if-an-array-contains-all-elements-in-another-array)

Comment: Your if-statement seems fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
valid = Arrays.asList(colors).contains(guess)
```

Comment: If `guess = "GRB"` then `valid` would be `false`. (Note the permutation.) I've understood that this would be required, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake on my part.

The code was in the right way, just overlooked some simple things

`guess.matches("[RGBPOY]+")` was the manual, working piece of code.

The string `Colors` just printed RGBPOY.

Meaning I missed a few things to get this to work.
By either doing this

```
Colors = "[" + Colors + "]+";
if(guess.matches("Colors")) {
}
```

or this

```
if(guess.matches("["+stringArray+"]+")) {
        }
```

The code worked as if it was put in manually since both were [RGBPOY]+