# Using an ArrayList to search within other ArrayList

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure out a way to use an `ArrayList` (2 or more indexes) to search within another `ArrayList`. For example, if `list = [4,5,6,2,3,5,6]` and `searchlist = [5,6]`, index should = 1.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: so are you looking for the occurrence of the numbers in the searchlist to be in your list in the order that it is in in searchlist? and it return the index?

Comment: you want to search the second list within the first list.. right..??

Comment: @mig Yea so if searchlist = [3,5], then index should = 4

Comment: See a similar post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940194/find-an-array-inside-another-larger-array

Comment: @Dileep Yea I want to search searchlist inside list

Comment: so what happens if 5, 6 are present but not together.. like 5,2,6

Comment: Collections.binarySearch() method may be helpful--> 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List, T)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List has subList and equals. That's all you need.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class TEST
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(2,3);

    for (int i=0; i<list1.size()-list2.size(); ++i) {
        if (list1.subList(i, i+list2.size()).equals(list2)) {
            System.out.println("found: "+i);
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("not found");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers to your current indices

```
public int search(int[] list, int[] searchList) {
  int listIndex = 0;
  int searchListIndex = 0;
  int foundIndex = -1;

  while (listIndex != list.length) {
    if (list[listIndex] == searchList[searchListIndex]) {
      if (searchListIndex == 0) {
        foundIndex = listIndex;
      }
      listIndex++;
      searchListIndex++;
    }
    else {
      listIndex++;
      searchListIndex = 0;
      foundIndex = -1;
    }
  }
  return foundIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the arrays in a nested loop.  Then compare all values.  If all values match up, then return the index:

```
list = [4,5,6,2,3,5,6]
searchlist = [5,6]

limit = list.size - serachList.size - 1

#make sure list's size is greater than or equal to searchList's size
for(i = 0 to limit)
    for(j = 0 to searchList.size-1)
        if(list[i + j] != searchList[j]) #found mismatch, so move on
            break
        if(j = searchList.size-1) #found complete match
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea is to run a loop, get the first value of the searchlist and find that value in the other list. If you find the number, increment the indices of both the lists and check the values again, continue until the end of searchlist or until the end of the other list.

I am not posting the code as I would rather you try yourself first, and come back if you are stuck anywhere.