# Search array within another array - Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to find an array within another array like

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b=[2,3,4]
c=[2,4,5]

// b is child of a, but c is NOT child of a.
```

Well I know that using Brute-force approach I can find the array within another array. But I want to know that is there any algo that can help me ... or (as I am using JAVA so) is there any built-in feature in JAVA that can help me ?

Comment: what is "bootforce" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned here :

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3940684/351861:

```
public static int findArray(Integer[] array, Integer[] subArray)
{
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(array), Arrays.asList(subArray));
}
```

Java has builting features for that, apparently.

Comment: Good ! Thanks. Just curious ... can you please let me know that what algo is behind the `Collections.indexOfSubList()` ... so that I can have good idea about this function's algorithm - as I am much concerned about algorithms.

Comment: certainly - this is java, after all : http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Collections-source.html

Comment: Consider adding to answer fact that it will not work for arrays of primitive types like `int[]`. We would need to use `Integer[]` instead because of how generics works.

Comment: i edited my comment - the first link was about old versions of java, apparently.