# Finding a sequence of bytes in a ByteArray

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I need to find a sequence of bytes within a `ByteArray`, but there doesn't seem to be any direct operations to do so. What's the most direct route to determining if a particular sequence of bytes exists within a `ByteArray`?

For example, I'd like to capture the range of a sequence (or `null`) with something like this:

```
val searchArray = arrayOf(0xF1.toByte(), 0xF2.toByte(), 0xF4.toByte(), 0xF8.toByte())
val range = myByteArray.range(of: searchArray)
```

I'd also be happy with just the starting index, since I always know the size of my search array.

Comment: Maybe you can do it by converting your Byte array to String then use the string methods to find the index

Comment: I'll let this here... http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/search-a-byte-array-for-a-byte-sequence

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940194/find-an-array-inside-another-larger-array

Comment: Thanks @GriffeyDog - your link got me to the solution that worked the best for my situation. Since I'm doing Android dev, I have access to Google Guava, which provides `Bytes.indexOf(ByteArray, ByteArray)`.

Comment: @AlecSanger pls, create an answer for this :)

Answer (score 4):

its too simple to add guava just for it:

```kotlin
fun ByteArray.findFirst(sequence: ByteArray,startFrom: Int = 0): Int {
    if(sequence.isEmpty()) throw IllegalArgumentException("non-empty byte sequence is required")
    if(startFrom < 0 ) throw IllegalArgumentException("startFrom must be non-negative")
    var matchOffset = 0
    var start = startFrom
    var offset = startFrom
    while( offset < size ) {
        if( this[offset] == sequence[matchOffset]) {
            if( matchOffset++ == 0 ) start = offset
            if( matchOffset == sequence.size ) return start
        }
        else
            matchOffset = 0
        offset++
    }
    return -1
}
```